# is Context in Android an implementation of a complex Strategy design pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin, android-context, strategy-pattern

I was reading several guides and one book about the `Strategy` pattern. I noticed that in all the guides there is a referall to a `Context`class that favoring delegation over implementation decide for some specific behaviors.
As I manage in android the class, object `Context` on daily basis, I would like to know if the SDK engineers tought at the Android `Context`as a concrete (complex) implementation of the strategy pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), the Strategy design pattern enables selecting an algorithm at runtime (where multiple possible implementations exist). The `Context` class does not encapsulate any single algorithm. And for the services that it allows to access, there are no multiple possible implementations selected at runtime; there's just a single implementation provided by the OS.

Therefore, no, the `Context` class has nothing in common with the `Strategy` pattern.

Comment: so selecting an algorithm at runtime, because `composition is better than inheritance` mantra, this I guess justifies Kotlin come with an inbuilt `lazy by delegate` command in Kotlin. You say `Context` does not encapsulate some algorithm, this suggests me that encapsulation is for what changes, this should be an ulterior proof that we are out of scope for the application of a `Strategy` pattern!. Thank  your very much, reply accepted && upvoted

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns represent the best practices used by experienced object-oriented software developers. It is naive to believe in a platform like Android this is not applied. For example, a design pattern when designing Android Context would be when dealing with different screen sizes. The context has instruction based on a Strategy Design Pattern to deal with so many different screen sizes.
I found this to be the simplest and most useful tutorial for design patterns with example of using context class.

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/index.htm
```

Comment: yeah the source you mention is one of them I studied, interesting reply regarding the different screen size,  I am going to upvote you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `Context` is **reference** that holds global information about an "**Application environment**".

This is an **abstract class** whose implementation is provided by the **Android system**.

It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

In short, it's reference about things running inside application *(you can assume it as global pointer to application process registry to be used in application environment, *in my opinion)*.

You can check out more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context).

Comment: ok thanks nice to know, but I would not expect a link to the official guide, But a clear repy to my OP questions `a) yes/no is a strategy pattern`  and `b) why? `    I guess you are implicitly saying not, is not a strategy pattern, but a simple abstract class, correct?

Comment: Yeah, **according to my knowledge**, it's bound to specific application. So, yes it's strategy pattern but it's implementation as simple abstract class is also true. because, almost all **SDK components** are direct or indirect child to this class.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your explanation, I am going to wait replies so to accept the one  nearer to my question